# Theoretical calculations of of the number of bits needed in receive window size

Tags: ethernet

**Alright, so I have a question as listed below:**

Suppose you are designing a sliding window protocol for a 10 Mbps point-to-point link to the moon, which has a one-way latency of 2.0 seconds.  Assuming that each frame carries 5KB of data, what is the minimum number of bits you need for the sequence number if RWS = SWS?

**What I have worked out so far is:**

SWS = RTT x Bandwidth / Framesize

10,000,000 bps * 4 seconds = 40,000,000 bits  is the through put

5000 Bytes = 40,000 bits per frame is the size of each frame

40,000,000 bits/ 40,000 bits = 1000 bits

SWS = 1000 bits

**According to the instructor there are two more steps past this to get the answer, and they are:** "First, compute MaxSeqNum based on SWS.

Then, compute the number of bits you need for the sequence number.  For example, if MaxSeqNum is 1000, you will need at least 10 bits for all possible sequence number, 2^10 =1024 > 1000."

**I can't figure out how to calc MaxSeqNum based of SWS**

**And i'm not sure how in the second part you get 10 bits because 2^10... that part doesn't make any sense either. Why is it only 10 bits when the SWS equals 1000 bits?? Where does 1024 come into play?**

What i'm looking for is the formula needed to calculate this, or a similar example solved that I can derive a formula or method of solving this from.

Comment: Unfortunately, homework, and any educational questions in general, for certification or degree programs, are specifically off-topic for this forum. Please see the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You were doing fine until you got here:

```
40,000,000 bits/ 40,000 bits = 1000 bits 
SWS = 1000 bits
```

The unit of measure of SWS is not bits, but frames.  So the question becomes, how big a binary number do you need to represent 1000 (frames)?  The answer, as you've stated, is 10 bits.  That's because it takes at least 10 bits to represent 1000 (2^10).

Comment: +1, but, of course, he originally had written that it was a homework question, and he edited after my comment.

Comment: Let's discuss this on Meta...

Comment: Start on chat, first?